# Replace Div in AJAX Response before appending to DOM

Tags: ajax, replace, response, fade, pjax

I am creating an AJAX transition between to pages where I have a hero image which stays the same on both pages.
After clicking on a link, I center the image, add the new HTML behind and fadeOut the center Image.
The problem is, even with a cached image (it is the same file) I see the image appearing suddenly in the behind (from AJAX response, rendering after appending to DOM) when fading out the image in the front.

Even by adding a little delay to the fadeout of the image in front, the image in the back is still no ready. (Probably the rendering just takes more time).

My options would be to wait for the Ajax image div to have rendered completely (which I don't know how to do), or – and that is what I'd like to try:
Replace (copy) the image within the AJAX response before adding it to the DOM.

Is this even possible, and will it help improving the performance?
I will also try to replace the div immediately after replacing the content with the AJAX response.

Any hints are still very welcome.

cheers

Answer (score 1):

You could set the css `z-index` property so that the top image stays on the top. And set an event listener so when the image underneath is finished loading you can fade out the top image.

```
$('#bottom-img').on('load', function() {
   $('#top-img').fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well thanks for the answer. This is what I meant. This would require some waiting for the image to finish loading and then fadeOut the top image. But I got a nicer solution:

Because the two images are exactly the same, I replace the content in the back (ajax response), and immediately after I copy the image on top into the ajax response (so I replace the image with an already loaded one).

Then I fade Out immediately.
This gives me a very smooth looking transition and the downside of the «waiting until loaded» is gone.

(In comparison to my initial question, where I wanted to replace the image within the ajax response before adding it to the DOM, I now add it to the DOM and manipulate it immediately.)

Thanks anyway.
Cheers